# What does insert-dimensional images ..." mean in the context of optimisation?

Tags: html, css

I do not know why I get the comment "insert-dimensional images ..."
[When I check the site in terms of its load time](http://gtmetrix.com/)
I got it and still I get this remark.
I'd love help how to do this right.

It is important to note the page was validated - WC3HTML 4.01 + WC3SCC.

http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/gallery.php

Comment: I just do not know why when I check the page loading speed link I wrote -
I get a comment "insert dimension images" 114 - 72.
I just mentioned that my site has a full validation ...!

Answer (score 1):

Boker tov! It means that GTmetrix suggests that you specify your images' or placeholders' dimensions (width/height) in the HTML or CSS so a viewer's browser can reserve their space in the layout and continue constructing the DOM, even if the images still need time to download. Or, you have specified dimensions but serve images which are too large so the viewer's browser has to scale them down. Both issues have an impact on a site's performance.

Comment: As you can see in the code - I got the dimensions of the images.
And yet there is a note about the small picture dimensions (Dimensions: 114 x 72)
I do not understand why?
http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/gallery.php

Comment: Yes, the source HTML on load has images with the width and height specified as should be. Maybe you have some dynamic content like large images or videos that are large and scaled to fit by the viewer's browser? Otherwise, I don't know. Have you tried http://www.webpagetest.org/ or http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ and others to see if maybe the fault lies with GTmetrix? Mazel tov!